# Is it possible to show notification in MacOSX or Safari?

Tags: views

I'm using Drupal latest version with lot of modules.
As you know, websites can Show notification in Notification center and/or Safari in Mac OSX.
I see that, Wordpress has a module for this.

Is it possible to do it for Drupal?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what the Wordpress module does.

But for the server running the website you can send notifications to the OS using [Drush Notify](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_notify) (built into Drush version 6).

From the readme it has a few example functions:

- drush_notify_send(): Send a message to notifications center and audio.
- drush_notify_send_text(): Send a message to notification center.
- drush_notify_send_audio(): Send a message to audio system.